# Jquery form with method="put" now broken

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I have a very basic form:

```
<form name="input" action="fly.cgi" method="put">
  Order Number:
  <input type="text" name="OrderNumber" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I added the jquery cdn CSS and js from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-template.html

I've read http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html but it doesn't seem like jquery supports the put method.

I did find this http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/9132_put-and-delete-with-jquery but not sure how to implement it.

FYI. The fly.cfi is not mine and I cannot change it.

Here is the full code. No luck still. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. http://pastebin.com/1AVsvQLP

Comment: Thanks munim.  Posting from iPhone couldn't get the code block to work.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

As @Munim said, you can't submit a `form` through PUT, but you can "send" it using `XMLHTTPRequest`.

So for example, this will work (assuming your form has the `myform` id):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "fly.cgi",
  data: $('#myform').serialize(),
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert('everything was OK');
  }
});
```

Note that by default when you submit a `form` the browser loads the new location, in this way you `PUT` data using AJAX, so there won't be a redirect.

Comment: Thank you!  This is a bit above my head as I'm still new to js. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: PUT http://mysite.com/fly.cgi 403 (Forbidden)

f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.6.4.min.js:4

f.extend.ajaxjquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
a.mobile.loadPagejquery.mobile-1.0.min.js:54
a.mobile.changePagejquery.mobile-1.0.min.js:59
(anonymous function)jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js:62
Ljquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
f.event.handlejquery-1.6.4.min.js:3
f.event.add.i.handle.k

Comment: The web server returns the 403 status code, so it's not jQuery's fault.

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms (up to HTML version 4 and XHTML 1) only support GET and POST as HTTP request methods. XHTML 2.0 will support GET, POST, PUT and DELETE for forms.

A workaround for this for methods through POST by using a hidden form field which is read by the server and dispatch accordingly.

Comment: But if I strip the page of any js or CSS the form submit works fine.  It's adding the jquery js that breaks it. Any more details on this method?